# What can be said about extension of a $n$-nilpotent ring by another $n$-nilpotent ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $0\to A \to C \to B \to 0$ be a short exact sequence of rings.
Assume that $A$ and $B$ are two $n$-nilpotent rings.

> Is $C$ a nilpotent ring too?

By $n$-nilpotency of a  ring  $R$, I mean $x_1x_2x_3\dotsb x_n=0, \;\forall x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\in R$

**Motivation:** A $Z^*$ algebra is a $C^*$ algebra whose all elements are zero divisor. The apparent evidences shows that one may prove that an extention of a $Z^*$ algebra by another $Z^*$ algebra is again a $Z^*$ algebra.  But in reality it is not the case. One can find a counter example. So this situation for zero divisor is a motivation for this post.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/), such as your own thoughts on the problem, any attempts you have made, anything about your background or knowledge which might be relevant, and/or any related theorems or definitions which you think might apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I'm not missing something silly, but can't you just argue directly that the product of $n^2$ elements in $C$ is zero? Explicitly, since the product of any $n$ elements in $C$ lies in $A$, if $x_{1,1},x_{1,2},\ldots,x_{n,n} \in C$ are $n^2$ elements, then $$
   \underbrace{x_{1,1} \cdot x_{1,2}\cdot \ldots x_{1,n}}_{\in A} \cdot \ldots \cdot \underbrace{x_{n,1}\cdot\ldots \cdot x_{n,n}}_{\in A}
$$ is a product of $n$ elements in $A$, and thus must be zero in $C$ since $A \to C$ is injective.

Comment: Thank  you very much for your answer. By the  way is  an extension of a 2-niplotent ring  by a  2  nilpotent ring again a  2 nilpotent ring?

Comment: I wouldn't think so :P I guess you can take the extension of (commutative, unital) rings $0 \to k[T]/T^2 \xrightarrow{T \mapsto T^2} k[T]/T^4 \to k[T]/T^2 \to 0$ and pass to the nilradical ideals (which are nilpotent rings, according to your definition) $0 \to k\cdot T / T^2 \to k\cdot T / T^4 \to k\cdot T /T^2 \to 0$ which is a $4$-nilpotent ring, given as the extension of two $2$-nilpotent rings.